# What are some viable strategies to detecting duplicates in a large json file when you need to store the duplicates?

Tags: python, json, data-structures

I have an extremely large set of data stored in json that is too large to load in memory. The json fields contain data about users and some metadata - however, there are certainly some duplicates. I would like to go through this file and curate it, merging the duplicates in a specific way.

However, I am not sure what the best practice to do so is. I thought of using a bloom filter, but a bloom filter won't let me know what the duplicate is a duplicate *of*, so I cannot exactly merge. Is there something I could read/see on what the best practice for something like this is? What are some industry standards? All of this needs to be done in python.

Answer (score 1):

You can partition the records by hash value into smaller sets that fit into memory, remove duplicates in each set, and then reassemble them back into one file.

Comment: What if there are duplicates across sets (say,  set 1 has element A and set 3 has element A - let us also assume that there exist no other duplicates, so we couldn't make set 1 and set 3 small enough to compare them because we'd need more memory I guess)

Comment: 'partition by hash value' means you hash in such a way that all duplicates will have the same hash value, so they will go in the same set.

Comment: are there any good resources you know about that I could use? How do I partition things by hash value? If I have 20GB of data... how do I sift through all of it? Do I store the hash set in different files, for example? Like, store it as a json object or something? I'm doing this in python by the way. Generally somewhat confused on how I should do this.

Comment: You don't need a hash set structure. You just open, say, 128 different output files for writing.  Then, read through your 20GB of data, hash each record, use the first 7 bits of the hash to choose an output file, and then write the record to that file.  You end up with 128 200MB files instead of 1 20GB file, and you can then process each one independently.